# Centos7 starting very slowly?

Tags: centos

My Centos7 starts very slowly. I do not know what is the cause. This problem appeared after I upgraded it to a new version. 
Can you, please, help me solve the problem? If more details are needed I will present them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you believe yourself that more details might be needed in order to diagnose?

Comment: @gwillie I think I was not very explicit,because I only specified  the problem in my question. There might be a lot of causes.